# Java jsonObject.get() returns null or an empty object for specific key

Tags: java, android, json, get

Here's the [JSON response](https://paste.ofcode.org/WULkWyYWk5A5whvcJUYUWP).

The following works:

```
jsonObject.get("title").getAsString();
jsonObject.get("author").getAsJsonObject().get("profile_photo").getAsString();
```

but `jsonObject.get("primary_photo").getAsString()` (from line 60) returns an Unsupported Exception: null error. I've tried replacing `getAsString()` with `toString()` but the latter returns an empty string.

Comment: Which JsonObject class you use in the code?

Comment: Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42652448/4056108)  i have had the same issue.

Comment: @Elka I imported this `com.google.gson.JsonObject;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Use `optJSONObject` and `optString` in your code . And the root is `[]`,so you should use `JSONArray`

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
         //  use optJSONObject
         JSONObject author = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optJSONObject("author");
         // use optString , it did not return null
         String profile_photo = author.optString("profile_photo");
         String primary_photo = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("primary_photo");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Gson**

```
JsonArray jsonElements = new JsonParser().parse(response).getAsJsonArray();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonElements.size(); i++) {
        JsonObject jObject = jsonElements.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        // edited here 
        String primary_photo = jObject.get("primary_photo").getAsString();
        JsonObject author = jObject.getAsJsonObject("author");
        String profile_photo = author.get("profile_photo").getAsString();
}
```

Comment: I don't have any issues with the author and its nested object profile_photo. My issue is with the `primary_photo` key (line 60).

Comment: I edited it .@Bargain23

Comment: shouldn't this `author.optString("author")` be `author.optString("primary_photo")`?

Comment: It should be `String primary_photo = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("primary_photo");` in your code .

Answer (score 1):

I think the Problem is, that your JSON response contains an Array. You have to create an JSONArray from the response-string and than iterate about it to get your values. Or if this array always contains one object:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

Comment: The get method is performed inside a `for` loop.

Comment: Why you use Gson ? Android comes with an own library: 
    org.json.JSONObject

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try {
            JSONArray jarr=new JSONArray(response);   // response is whole json response
            for (int i=0;i<jarr.length();i++){
                JSONObject jobj=jarr.getJSONObject(i);   
                String primary_photo=jobj.getString("primary_photo");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this,

try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

         JSONObject author = jsonArray.get(i).getJSONObject"author");

         String profile_photo = author.getString("author");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```